# How does screenwings stop every screenshot?

Tags: wpf, windows, screenshot, desktop

What API/Functions does screenWings use to blackout the screenshot and prevent them?

I know about SetWindowDisplayAffinity to prevent the running application to be screenShoted and IsScreenCaptureEnabled ( this one is for UWP which is not our case )

Comment: It’s likely SetWindowDisplayAffinity. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: No, I did not but does SetWindowDisplayAffinity work for the whole OS, because when launching the program I can't take any screenshot with any programs for anything, everything is black

Comment: The entire screenshot is black, or every window in the screenshot is black, or every window belonging to the target application is black, but others are fine? It's possible that they intercept the `PrntScrn` key-combination. What happens if you use Windows' Snipper tool?

Comment: Every Screenshot in every scenario ( all screen, specific window, specific region .... ) is black using any tool ( including Snipper tool, other tools like shareX and scripts I wrote using python with different libraries ), and of course the PrntScrn also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, as @Dai pointed to test in the comment, it was `SetWindowDisplayAffinity`, I tested it myself and it worked as predicted, not in all scenarios ( as you have to create a window and make it on foreground then apply the function on it .... ) but it is it